# Dual Boot, separate M2 / NVMe hard drives. Windows not showing

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, nvme

### Here's the problem broken down:

- I have two M2 drives
- One already has Windows 10 installed
- I installed Ubuntu on the second
- During install I noticed the windows drive was not showing in the
  "something else"  menu.
- I created the necessary partitions anyway, on the only drive that was
  showing, and installed ubuntu
- Once installed, I opened a terminal and tried lsblk but only the ubuntu drive is
  listed. no other.

### Possible complications:

My motherboard (ASUS Prime Z390M-plus) seemingly only allows the second m2 drive in the slot that the Windows drive inhabited (im not sure how to change that)

I had already installed Ubuntu correctly, swapped the hard drives back (testing) and had to remove grub manually because it was just booting to Grub cmd line instead of menu

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction... feeling pretty n00by rn.

thank you x

Comment: Looks like one configuration for that system is the two drives configured as RAID-1.  Did you disable that to use them as two separate drives?

Comment: So after much head scratching... discovered the second "NVMe" was in fact an M2 SATA drive (d'oh) so threw three sheets to the wind and switched to AHCI... which, it turns out, was a really stupid thing to do. 
Literally did it in the BIOS in a hurry instead of doing it properly in the command line.
Got my Grub menu back, got Ubuntu running fine on the SATA M2.. and am currently re-downloading the Windows 10 ISO to recover/ reInstall windows.
Thank heavens for the cloud and backup drives.

Thanks for taking time out to answer though.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK everyone! one of the M2 drives was SATA! always double check they're both NVMe before you cry for help.

Switched storage config from RAID to AHCI and Grub menu is back, Ubuntu is running on the SATA m2 and windows is currently repairing itself/ reinstalling because I didnt switch to ACHI carefully in CMD.

**LESSONS LEARNED:**

- Always check your M2 type
- NEVER just switch to AHCI... do it properly in command prompt (as
  admin)